# How to find pattern inside a specific pattern and print both of them

Tags: unix, awk, sed, text-processing

I want to only print server name as header and whatever sas service is not up inside it.if everything is up inside server it should not be printed.

File content-

```
he2unix554 Server: 

SAS servers status:

SAS OLAP Server 1 is UP

SAS Object Spawner 1 is UP

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up

SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up

he2unix555 Server: 

SAS servers status:

SAS OLAP Server 1 is UP

SAS Object Spawner 1 is UP

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up

SAS Environment Manager Agent is UP

he2unix556 server:

SAS servers status:

SAS OLAP Server 1 is UP

SAS Object Spawner 1 is UP

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is UP

SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up

he2unix557 Server

SAS servers status:

SAS OLAP Server 1 is NOT up

SAS Object Spawner 1 is UP

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is UP

SAS Environment Manager Agent is UP

he2unix558 Server

SAS Web Infrastructure Data Server is UP

SAS OLAP Server 1 is UP

SAS Object Spawner 1 is UP

SAS DIP Job Runner 1 is UP

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is UP

SAS Cache Locator Service ins_41415 is NOT up

SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up

he2unix559 Server

SAS OLAP Server 1 is UP

SAS Object Spawner 1 is UP

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is UP

SAS Environment Manager Agent is UP
```

***Desired Output-***

```
   he2unix554 Server: 

    SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up

    SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up

    he2unix555 Server: 

    SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up

    he2unix556 server:

    SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up

    he2unix557 Server:

    SAS OLAP Server 1 is NOT up

    he2unix558 Server:

    SAS Cache Locator Service ins_41415 is NOT up
```

i tried below which is giving me server header even if everything is up inside it.

**sed -n '/^he2unix5/ { p } ; /NOT up$/ { p }' sasserverstatus.log**

```
he2unix554 Server: 

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up

SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up

he2unix555 Server: 

SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up

he2unix556 server:

SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up

he2unix557 Server:

SAS OLAP Server 1 is NOT up

he2unix558 Server:

SAS Cache Locator Service ins_41415 is NOT up

**he2unix559 Server:**   #don't want this in output
```

Comment: are there really empty lines between each pair of lines?

Answer (score 0):

**Awk** is more suitable for such cases:

```
awk '/^he2unix/{ sn=$0; f=1; sas=0 }f && /NOT up/{ if(!sas++) print sn; print $0 }' file
```

The output:

```
he2unix554 Server: 
SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up
SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up
he2unix555 Server: 
SAS CONNECT Spawner 1 is NOT up
he2unix556 server:
SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up
he2unix557 Server
SAS OLAP Server 1 is NOT up
he2unix558 Server
SAS Cache Locator Service ins_41415 is NOT up
SAS Environment Manager Agent is NOT up
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it does exactly what i wanted.  can you please elaborate what it is doing. i know only basic of awk.

Answer (score 0):

It may be laughable :-) but the following sed command seems to work for me:

```
sed -n '/^he2unix5/ {h}; /NOT up$/ {x;H;p;x;P;s/.*//;x}' sasserverstatus.log
```

Comment: great. it worked. can you explain {x;H;p;x;P;s/.*//;x}'

Comment: You can make the second bracketed sequence a little simpler: `{H;g;p;s/.*//;x}`

Comment: You're too kind @Beta that's much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
sed -n '/^he2unix5/h;/NOT up$/{x;G;s/^\n//;p;s/.*//;x}' sasserverstatus.log
```

Or to keep your look :

```
sed -n '/^he2unix5/{1bA;s/^/\n/;:A;s/$/\n/;h};/NOT up$/{x;G;p;s/.*//;x}' sasserverstatus.log
```